# iTerm session not unique

Tags: bash, iterm2, iterm

I have a possibly simple issue, but can't resolve it. I recently downloaded iTerm and have it setup using zsh, but when using tabs they are always duplicated.

For example I open two tabs A and B using `CMD+T`. I type `ls` in A and it works as expected, but tab B also does the same! If I use the standard macOS Terminal this does not happen. It also does not occur if open two separate iTerm windows.

Any ideas?

EDIT - iTerm version is `Build 3.0.15`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself.

User error on my part, and a difference between Terminal and iTerm. I was switching tabs using `CMD+SHIFT+ARROWS`. This moves the tab, you need to use `CMD+ARROWS` to jump between tabs.